# can the same docker port be used for two different applications?

Tags: docker

If we have two applications `app1.py` and `app2.py` both running in  docker container as flask services with following commands:

```
docker run -p 5000:5002 app1.py
docker run -p 9000:5002 app2.py
```

Is it possible to keep the same docker port `5002` for both containers?
Secondly, if I use **app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)** in flask endpoint.py file which is used for image building, is `port=5000` the docker port in container or the port available externally on host?

Comment: I can't confirm for Flask service, but normally Docker maps port like `Host:Container`. So standard Docker you can use the same port. As long as each container is on an isolated network (not a bridge).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each container runs in an isolated network namespace, so every one can listen on the same port and they won’t conflict.  Inside your application code the port you listen on is the container-internal port, and unless you get told in some other way (like an HTTP `Host:` header) you have no way of knowing what ports you’ve been remapped to externally.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to keep the same docker port `5002` for both containers?

Yes, of course. Typically every container runs in an isolate network namespace, which means containers cannot communicate with each unless they are configured to do so. What confuses you maybe that containers do communicate with each other well by default, which should thank Docker network default setting. But there are still other use cases. You may see more about **The container Network Model** and **network namespace** [here](http://success.docker.com/article/networking).

> Is `port=5000` the port in container or the port valid externally on host?

It’s the port in container with no doubt. We could notice it is a user-defined argument for function `run()` in Flask. Since Flask application runs in container, so `5000` will be the port which Flask app would listen on in container.
We should map it out if we wanna access `5000` on host(outside of container). The [flag `-p`](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#connect-using-network-port-mapping) would help you.

Hope this helps~